# C# Counting quantity and formatting orders listed in observablecollection

Tags: foreach, observablecollection

I have orders with order number, item and quantity in observablecollection. I want to make string where is first order number and under that is listed the items and counted quantities (without zero quantities). Like:

order1

apple 2

lemon 1

banana 1

---

order2

apple 3

banana 3

---

I can do it with my code but it cant be the right way to do it. So I am asking how it should be done or what is a good way to do it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace OrdersArrange
{

public static class EnumerableExtensions{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var e in enumerable)
        {
            action(e);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Order> _order;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CreateOrders();

        ListOfOrdersToString();
    }

    private void CreateOrders()
    {
        _order = new ObservableCollection<Order>();

        var order = new Order()
        {
            OrderNumber = "1111",
            OrderItem = "Apple",
            ItemCount = 2
        };

        _order.Add(order);

        order = new Order()
        {
            OrderNumber = "1111",
            OrderItem = "Banana",
            ItemCount = 0
        };

        _order.Add(order);

        order = new Order()
        {
            OrderNumber = "2222",
            OrderItem = "Banana",
            ItemCount = 5
        };

        _order.Add(order);

        order = new Order()
        {
            OrderNumber = "2222",
            OrderItem = "Banana",
            ItemCount = 1
        };

        _order.Add(order);

        order = new Order()
        {
            OrderNumber = "1111",
            OrderItem = "Banana",
            ItemCount = 3
        };

        _order.Add(order);

        order = new Order()
        {
            OrderNumber = "3333",
            OrderItem = "Banana",
            ItemCount = 1
        };

        _order.Add(order);

        order = new Order()
        {
            OrderNumber = "3333",
            OrderItem = "Lemon",
            ItemCount = 2
        };

        _order.Add(order);

        order = new Order()
        {
            OrderNumber = "1111",
            OrderItem = "Lemon",
            ItemCount = 0
        };

        _order.Add(order);

        order = new Order()
        {
            OrderNumber = "2222",
            OrderItem = "Banana",
            ItemCount = 2
        };

        _order.Add(order);

        order = new Order()
        {
            OrderNumber = "1111",
            OrderItem = "Lemon",
            ItemCount = 1
        };

        _order.Add(order);

        order = new Order()
        {
            OrderNumber = "1111",
            OrderItem = "Apple",
            ItemCount = 0
        };

        _order.Add(order);
    }

    private void ListOfOrdersToString()
    {
        // List for order numbers.
        var listOfOrderNumbers = new List<string>();
        string ordersList = "This contains the orders: " + "\n";

        // Loop throught order numbers.
        for (int i = 0; i < _order.Count; i++)
        {
            // Check order number.
            if (!listOfOrderNumbers.Contains(_order.ElementAt(i).OrderNumber))
            {
                // Add order number to list.
                listOfOrderNumbers.Add(_order.ElementAt(i).OrderNumber);

                // Add order number line to string.
                ordersList += _order.ElementAt(i).OrderNumber + "\n";

                // List for item names.
                var listOfItems = new List<string>();

                // Loop throught items.
                for (int o = 0; o < _order.Count; o++)
                {
                    // Check item number.
                    if (!listOfItems.Contains(_order.ElementAt(o).OrderItem))
                    {
                        // Add item to list.
                        listOfItems.Add(_order.ElementAt(o).OrderItem);

                        // Count quantity.
                        int quantity = 0;
                        _order.Where(x => x.OrderNumber == _order.ElementAt(i).OrderNumber).Where(x => x.OrderItem == _order.ElementAt(o).OrderItem).Where(x => x.ItemCount > 0).ForEach(a => quantity = (quantity + a.ItemCount));

                        if (quantity > 0)
                        {
                            ordersList += _order.ElementAt(o).OrderItem + "\t" + quantity + "\n";
                        }
                    }
                }

                ordersList += "-----------------------" + "\n";
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show(ordersList);
        Console.WriteLine(ordersList);

    }
}

public class Order
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

    public string OrderItem { get; set; }

    public int ItemCount { get; set; }
}
```

}

This prints out:
This contains the orders:

1111

Apple   2

Banana  3

Lemon   1

---

2222

Banana  8

---

3333

Banana  1

Lemon   2

---

Comment: What's wrong about that output? It looks the same format as your input.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that output. Just I doubt my solution is good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would make it in this way (I made it withoud compiler, so i hope there are not so many mistakes):

```
public void ListOfOrdersToString()
    {
        //somehow fill _order
        List<Order> _order = null;
        List<CompleteOrder> completeOrders = new List<CompleteOrder>();
        foreach (Order order in _order)
        {
            CompleteOrder completeOrder = completeOrders.Where(o => o.OrderID == Int32.Parse(order.OrderNumber)).SingleOrDefault();
            if (completeOrder == null)
            {
                completeOrder = new CompleteOrder();
                completeOrder.OrderID = Int32.Parse(order.OrderNumber);
                completeOrders.Add(completeOrder);
            }
            var count = completeOrder.OrderItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == order.OrderItem).Value;
            if (count == null)
            {
                completeOrder.OrderItems.Add(order.OrderItem, order.ItemCount);
            }
            else
            {
                count = count + order.ItemCount;
            }
        }
        print(completeOrders);
    }

    public void print(List<CompleteOrder> completeOrderList)
    {
        foreach (CompleteOrder co in completeOrderList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(co.OrderID);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in co.OrderItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + " " + entry.Value + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CompleteOrder
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<String, int> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I will try this later at the evening. Looks maybe simpler than my solution.

Comment: var count = completeOrder.OrderItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == order.OrderItem).Value; throws me exception: "Value cannot be null". Have to look at that.

Comment: Ah yes, I see, it has to be splitted into:
var count = completeOrder.OrderItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == order.OrderItem);
            if (count == null)
            {
                completeOrder.OrderItems.Add(order.OrderItem, order.ItemCount);
            }
            else
            {
                count = count.Value();
                count = count + order.ItemCount;
            }